# C# Error on Close

Tags: c#

When I close my C# application, I am getting the a windows sound that indicates an error.  However, when I debug through the close process, I get all the way back up into the Program class...

It gets past Application.Run(..), exits the static void Main() function, and then makes the error noise.

Other than the noise there is nothing indicative of an error.  I don't even know where to begin looking!  Any ideas?

Comment: What types of things is your program doing?  For example, is it starting new threads?

Comment: I thought I was starting threads, but the error happens even when I don't touch that code.  So, threads are not a factor.

Comment: I think you should post the code if any that you execute while the program is closed.
Also, how is the program closed? By using the close button?

Comment: It's also worth looking at the Windows event log.

Comment: Matt, did you solve it? Maybe you could leave a comment to explain what was wrong, you can even post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is going wrong in the cleanup, that could be very hard to find. There are two ways to attack this:

Enhance the chances of detecting it while you're still in control (in Main) by wrapping everything in your Main in a try/catch and add some code after the Application.Run to get as much of the cleanup going as possible. A few things I can think of:

```
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Collect at least 2 times, maybe more. In the same spirit, add a few Application.DoEvents() in the OnClosing of the MainForm.

The other approach is more dependent on your code, to take a stab in the dark: look for all static fields/properties you can set to null and Disposable objects you can Dispose deterministically on Exit.

And all this in combination with Fredrik Mörks suggestion for the UnhandledException event.

Comment: This cleared up the problem for me, and I just left it there while I continued developing the application, meaning to come back to it.  When I finally got around to removing it -- the problem no longer existed.

If I get some time, I will go back through my code changes and see where I made the change that seemed to magically fix the issue.  But thank you all for your fantastic advice!

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you could to in order to maybe get some information is to hook up event listeners for the AppDomain.UnhandledException and Application.ThreadException events. It's a long shot, but may provide some info. You could add the following in the beginning of the Main function to set them up, and have them show any exception info in a message box:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    });
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
    });

    // run your app
}
```

Comment: Fantastic idea -- Thank you!  However, these came up empty :(

Answer (score 1):

It only happens when you close your app or does it happen when you close any app?

My first thought would be that someone changed your windows sound scheme and set the close program sound to mess with you :).

Comment: This was my first thought :)  Unfortunately it is just in this single application.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code that raises custom events?  Could these processes still be running when the app tries to close in real-time?

Do you have any custom Dispose code that could be running at time of close?